# Simple way to read content of BluetoothGattDescriptor in Android BLE

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to get the content of a `BluetoothGattDescriptor` in Android.

I can read the `BluetoothGattCharacteristic` which returns the Descriptor.

When I try and read them this way:

```
byte[] b = descriptor.getValue();
            final byte[] data = descriptor.getValue();
            if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
                final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
                for (byte byteChar : data)
                    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
                Log.e("---", new String(data)+"\n"+stringBuilder.toString());
            }
```

I can see a string value "Characteristic 1"

I tried using the `BluetoothGattCharacteristic.getProperties()` which is supposedly 
Returns the properties of this characteristic. The explanation according to the android API is `"The properties contain a bit mask of property flags indicating the features of this characteristic."` If I do that I get a value of `10`. I have no experience working with `"BLE"` and especially with `bitmask flags`.

Is there a simpler way to read the Features supported by the BLE server device?

Comment: I found this [Android BLE SDK](https://github.com/xpg/GizwitsBLE) and it does a good job.